# Trying to change a recursive function to an iterative one

Tags: recursion

I'm trying to convert a recursive function to an iterative one. The part where the calculation for even/odd numbers differs is where I can't figure out how to get an iterative solution. The following is the function in question.

```
public static int a(int n)
{
    if(n==1) return 1;
    else if(n%2 == 0) return a(n/2)*4;
    else return (a((n-1)/2)+a((n+1)/2))*2;
}
```

This function is my solution to the problem described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5h3yTxeCew) (how many loops do you need to tie around the given number of hooks so that removing one hook unravels all remaining loops).

The resulting sequence is 1, 4, 10, 16, 28, 40, 52, 64, 88, 112, ... which does have some regularity in the values it's increasing by.

I mananged to get a solution for values in the 2^n sequence:
4^(log(n)/log(2))

However, is there an iterative solution for the full range?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it for a long time, I did find an iterative solution myself. It may not be optimal, as it's a lot more comlicated than the recursive solution (and A LOT slower than the recursive one).

```
public static int b(int n)
{
    int k = 1, result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(n, 2)); i++)
    {
        for (; k < ((n < (Math.Pow(2, i + 1))) ? n : (Math.Pow(2, i + 1))); k++)
        {
            result += (int)(3 * (Math.Pow(2, i)));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```